# Sequelize | (re)generate migration files from existing models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, migration, sequelize-cli

I'm using Sequelize and I'm currently creating migrations for my nodejs-application.
How can I regenerate the migration files when I changed the models?

Using `npx sequelize-cli model:generate` will create a migration file automatically. I want to generate these files without creating a new model.

Thinks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```bash
npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name Changes
```

Without adding attributes,
Then before running migration ("npx sequelize-cli db:migrate"),
Give the name of existing model or table in the code of newly generated migration file.

then simply run migration, new model will not be generated !